How do I log the usage of an excel based tool using forms or common shared Excel on Onedrive?
I have created an Excel-based tool for everyone's use and need to log the usage for my analysis purposes like who used the tool and what settings they did. The log can be using Excel of Microsoft Forms etc.
Now, I have written a code in VB to do this, but the issue occurs when multiple users use the tool simultaneously or before the Log Excel sheet on my OneDrive is synced/updated. In this case, the tool does not work at all and gets hanged. Below is the code I wrote.
'Log Usage into Excel sheet for analysis
'#########################Get Email ID

Dim outApp As Object, outSession As Object
Dim currentUserEmailAddress As String
Dim UserTrackingLastRow As Integer
currentUserEmailAddress = ""
On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

If outApp Is Nothing Then
    currentUserEmailAddress = "Cannot create Microsoft Outlook session."
    currentUserEmailAddress = "Not found"
Else
    'Set a NameSpace object variable with .Session property (same as .GetNamespace("MAPI"), to access       existing Outlook items, and get
    'current user name
    Set outSession = outApp.Session.CurrentUser
    'Get current user email address
    currentUserEmailAddress = outSession.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
    Set outApp = Nothing
End If

'Open shared excel sheet and log the usage
sfilename = "https://mycompany-    my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname/Documents/05.Shared%20Folder/User_Log.xlsm"
MacrosEnabled = True
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Visible = False
Set xlsheet = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=False,    ignorereadonlyrecommended:=True, Password:="Password@2024")

'Identify last used row
UserTrackingLastRow = xlsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Create Session ID with User Name initials and latest sequence
UserName = Split(Application.UserName, ",")
SessionID = Trim(Left$(UserName(1), 2)) & Left$(UserName(0), 1) & UserTrackingLastRow
Sheets("Tool Data Collection").Cells(10002, 10000).Value = SessionID
xlsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & UserTrackingLastRow + 1) = (UserTrackingLastRow)
xlsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & UserTrackingLastRow + 1) = SessionID
xlsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & UserTrackingLastRow + 1) = Application.UserName
xlsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & UserTrackingLastRow + 1) = currentUserEmailAddress
xlsheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & UserTrackingLastRow + 1) = Now

'Close Excel sheet
    xlsheet.Close SaveChanges:=True


Probably better to log into a database
